# PHP: Cause user to download a file that is hosted on a different server

Tags: php

If I do

```
$file='http://notmywebsite.com/verybigimage.png';
$newfile='test.png';
copy($file,$newfile);
```

will my server download `http://notmywebsite.com/verybigimage.png`?

If yes, how can I make my user download `http://notmywebsite.com/verybigimage.png` without that my server download it?

Comment: By "make your user download", do you mean bring up a download prompt or just straight up download it onto their computer?

Comment: @Palladium Bring up a download prompt. :)

Comment: Well, according to [this forum](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/prompt-file-download-of-external-file-577269.html) making people download external files is just the same as making them download local ones. So go ahead, knock yourself out, and break a leg.

Comment: Uh, do you want to copy the file server side by making the client download it instead of the server? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Mahn I am not understanding a lot, but I think it's that.

Comment: @user1365010 I answered, let me know if that helps, otherwise please give more detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to have the client (the user) download a file and then copy this file in the server in a seamless way, because these two environments are living in different systems — in order to do this, the client needs to upload the file back to the server after downloading it, which in turn would be a pain for the user and slower than simply letting the server download the file and copying it there, if the ultimate goal is having a copy of the file in the server.

Comment: My goal is just to make him download a file that is not on my server.

Comment: Ah I see, are you familiar with Javascript? This is a job for client-side code, ie using JS.

Comment: I want to put the image in a folder and maybe zip it (Then prompt the download). Is this possible in JS?

Comment: You'll have to copy it first server side to zip it, but yes, it should be possible otherwise. It's too broad though, I can't give you a single line of code that will do it, but look up file uploading/downloading tutorials with PHP+Javascript in google, I'm sure there are a ton.

Comment: Then, I won't zip it. But is it possible to make the user download a folder that contains a file not on my server?

Comment: Yeah, it should be possible with JS alone. Check out for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Yes, downloading it, but putting it in a folder?

Comment: Client side? Nope. Why would you need to do that anyway?

Comment: For example, if I want to download all images from https://www.google.com/search?num=10&hl=fr&safe=off&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=666&q=test&oq=test&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2109.2881.0.3392.4.4.0.0.0.0.316.891.0j2j1j1.4.0...0.0...1ac.sf5YW9pwyko . I would do this script so that I download a folder with all that images. Of course, I don't want to download them on the server and then download it in my computer (double time).

Comment: Hm, I would recommend setting up a local server then, that way you can run php on your pc directly and thus the server where you download and copy the images would effectively be your pc.

Comment: Thank you for all! I think I will do it that way, but I would be curious to know how one will have been able to do that.